# Extract partial line of text from text file

Tags: file, powershell, text, extract

I need to keep the first 5 characters from data being pulled from a text file.

Data looks like this:

```
S1831KWT0081
S2004KWT0083
S2351KWT0085
S0054KWT0087
```

Results should looks like this:

```
S1831
S2004
S2351
S0054
```

I can get it working when setting the variable within PowerShell:

```
PS> $a = "S1831KWT0081"
PS> $a.Substring(0, $a.IndexOf('K'))

S1831
```

but I'm stuck when trying to pull from a text file.

Comment: > But I'm stuck when trying to pull from a text file. How so? Could you give some examples of what you have tried? The only code you've given is what you've gotten to work.

Comment: $location = Get-Content "C:\location.txt"
$location.Substring(0, $location.IndexOf('K'))

Comment: `$location = Get-Content "C:\location.txt" | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf('K')) }`

Comment: This actually exposes the issue you're having - in your question, you treat each line as a separate entity. In your comment, you basically treat an entire array as a variable. :)

Comment: Amazing how easy it is once you see the solution. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you will need to parse the text file on a line-by-line basis. Basically treating each line as a value in an array.

```
Get-Content location.txt | foreach { $_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf('K')) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be a regular expression replacement:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt') -replace '^(.{5}).*', '$1'
```

That would also allow you more specific matches, e.g. like this:

```
$re = '^([a-z]\d{4}).*'
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt') -match $re -replace $re, '$1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show there always is more than one PoSh way ;-)

```
gc .\input.txt|%{$_.split('K')[0]}
```

Or the more verbose version

```
Get-Content .\input.txt | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.split('K')[0] }
```